# Marketing Automation module in Sitecore 9 with Marketer role

Tags: marketing-automation

Can we access Marketing Automation module in sitecore 9 with a `Marketer` role?

I am able to access this module as the admin user. But my marketing team is not able to access this module with `Marketer` role.

What role should be used to access this?

Comment: Page is flickering with Marketer role but working fine with Admin Role

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not clear what the Marketer role which you mentioned above, but to your question to access **Marketing Automation module**, you need to have the **"Marketing Automation Editors"**.

You can refer the detail of each and every role in Sitecore documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html)